# autofilling column values in stored procedure, called via trigger

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

Currently, I have bunch of triggers that do the same thing. This is copy-pasted for every table that needs this functionality.

```
delimiter $$

create trigger user_before_insert before insert on user for each row
begin
    set NEW.create_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    set NEW.create_user_id = @user_id;
    set NEW.modify_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    set NEW.modify_user_id = @user_id;
end$$

create trigger user_before_update before update on user for each row
begin
    set NEW.modify_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    set NEW.modify_user_id = @user_id;
end$$
```

Is it possible to wrap the lines that modify `OLD` and/or `NEW` into stored procedures that are called via triggers? Something like this:

```
delimiter $$

create procedure autofill_on_insert(inout NEW data_type) -- what would be the data_type?
begin
    set NEW.create_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    set NEW.create_user_id = @user_id;
    set NEW.modify_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    set NEW.modify_user_id = @user_id;
end$$

create procedure autofill_on_update(inout NEW data_type) -- what would be the data_type?
begin
    set NEW.modify_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    set NEW.modify_user_id = @user_id;
end$$

delimiter ;

create trigger user_before_insert before insert on user
    for each row call autofill_on_insert(NEW);
create trigger user_before_update before update on user
    for each row call autofill_on_update(NEW);
```

Additional question: if this is possible, is there any way to check if `NEW` contains specific columns? There are tables that do not have `modify_time` and `modify_user_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can say that NEW cannot be passed into the procedure, because NEW is an alias that represents a row. Procedure's arguments have to be scalar values, like INT, VARCHAR, etc..

About the 'SET NEW.create_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;'; if field `create_time` is a TIMESTAMP, you could set CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default value for it.

Comment: I can set `current_timestamp` as default value for `create_time`, but it is not enough - the problem is that if I use it for `create_time`, I can't set it as `on update` value for `modify_time`. I also cannot set `@user_id` as `default` or `on update` value for `create_user_id` and `modify_user_id`.

Comment: Yes, there only one TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE field must be. But you could add special TIMESTAMP field with ON UPDATE clause (that will be the first TIMESTAMP field); set DEFAULT NULL for modify_time and create_time fields; then (when select modify_time or create_time data) refer to that TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE field if value is null.