# Mysql multiple timestamp column update

Tags: php, mysql

Consider this:

```
    +---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
    | Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                               |
    +---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
    | email_address | varchar(100) | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                             |
    | create_date   | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
    | optin_date    | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
    | optout_date   | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
    +---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Using PHP, how can I make the `optin_date` and `optout_date` columns store the current timestamp?

Comment: Haven't really tried anything yet. I have this so far: `update table set optin_date = now()`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you need to have some 'timestamp on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' fields? They will have the SAME values after UPDATE.

Comment: @Devart What's the correct way?

Comment: Similar question (see the comments) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592049/autofilling-column-values-in-stored-procedure-called-via-trigger/5592925#5592925

Answer (score 3):

You can have only one current_timestamp column. For the second you have to use trigger on insert/update.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html